# Python generator pre-fetch?

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator that takes a long time for each iteration to run.  Is there a standard way to have it yield a value, then generate the next value while waiting to be called again?

The generator would be called each time a button is pressed in a gui and the user would be expected to consider the result after each button press.

EDIT: a workaround might be:

```
def initialize():
    res = next.gen()

def btn_callback()
    display(res)
    res = next.gen()
    if not res:
       return
```

Comment: the question is: why does to the generator take so long? The best way of solving the problem depends on that.

Comment: @Winston, in the case I'm working on, it reads an image file from disk and does some processing, but I'm also interested in the general question.

Comment: but your application will become unresponsive right after calling display(). Does that really solve the problem to your satisfaction?

Comment: @Winston, it will have to be unresponsive at some point when it's  processing. It seems better to be unresponsive while user is looking at the result than when user is waiting for the next result

Comment: No it doesn't. If you run the task in a thread or another process it will not become unresponsive.

Comment: @Wiston Ewert: "If you run the task in a thread".  Good point.  Not part of the proposed solution.

Comment: @foosion.  "It seems better to be unresponsive while user is looking at the result".  That's what a process is for.  To do work in the background while the foreground is waiting for the next GUI event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I wanted to do something like your workaround, I'd write a class like this:

```
class PrefetchedGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, generator):
         self._data = generator.next()
         self._generator = generator
         self._ready = True

    def next(self):
        if not self._ready:
            self.prefetch()
        self._ready = False
        return self._data

    def prefetch(self):
        if not self._ready:
            self._data = self._generator.next()
            self._ready = True
```

It is more complicated than your version, because I made it so that it handles not calling prefetch or calling prefetch too many times. The basic idea is that you call .next() when you want the next item. You call prefetch when you have "time" to kill.

Your other option is a thread..

```
class BackgroundGenerator(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, generator):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue(1)
        self.generator = generator
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for item in self.generator:
            self.queue.put(item)
        self.queue.put(None)

    def next(self):
            next_item = self.queue.get()
            if next_item is None:
                 raise StopIteration
            return next_item
```

This will run separately from your main application. Your GUI should remain responsive no matter how long it takes to fetch each iteration.

Comment: Should def init be followed by: threading.Thread.__init__(self)

Comment: I tried to use this by adding: gen = BackgroundGenerator(generator()), then calling next(gen, default), and got TypeError BackgroundGenerator object is not an iterator.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @foosion, I made BackgroundGenerator an iterable rather then an iterator. I changed it to an iterator. (I also tested it this time)

Comment: That appears to work nicely, except when I try to exit the program, at which point the program hangs.  I'm using tkinter as a gui and am just calling its quit function to exit.  Anything immediately spring to mind?

Comment: @foosion, add `self.daemon = True` to the thread constructor. By default python runs as long as any thread runs, and since I'm guessing you don't exhaust the iterator the thread never finishes. Setting the thread to daemon tells python its ok to exit even if this thread has not finished.

Comment: That did it. Runs rather smoothly now

Comment: you can replace `1` with any number `k`, if you want it to pre-fetch and hold in memory no more then `k` objects

Answer (score 8):

No.  A generator is not asynchronous.  This isn't multiprocessing.

If you want to avoid waiting for the calculation, you should use the `multiprocessing` package so that an independent process can do your expensive calculation.

You want a separate process which is calculating and enqueueing results.

Your "generator" can then simply dequeue the available results.

Comment: A simpler approach than multiprocessing might be to queue one result at the start, then on each button press show the queued result and call the generator to queue the next result.  I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: @foosion: It's still perfectly synchronous.  Generating the first two takes twice as long as generating the first one.  The time at each step after that is exactly the same.

Comment: @S. Lott:  if the work is being done while the user is studying the prior result, and a new results pops up as soon as the button is pressed, the user won't notice any delay.  If the work is being done after the user presses the button, the user sits there waiting for the result to appear.

Comment: @foosion:  It's still perfectly synchronous. If you want to do something while the user is thinking, you need to use a separate process (or sometimes a separate thread.)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with generators, just create your generator so that each `next` call alternates between getting the next value and returning it by putting in multiple `yield` statements.  Here is an example:

```
import itertools, time

def quick_gen():
    counter = itertools.count().next
    def long_running_func():
        time.sleep(2)
        return counter()
    while True:
        x = long_running_func()
        yield
        yield x

>>> itr = quick_gen()
>>> itr.next()   # setup call, takes two seconds
>>> itr.next()   # returns immediately
0
>>> itr.next()   # setup call, takes two seconds
>>> itr.next()   # returns immediately
1
```

Note that the generator does not automatically do the processing to get the next value, it is up to the caller to call `next` twice for each value.  For your use case you would call `next` once as a setup up, and then each time the user clicks the button you would display the next value generated, then call `next` again for the pre-fetch.

Comment: Rather than calling twice, see my workaround edit for what might be a simpler approach

Comment: Now he needs to call the generator twice as many times, and on every second one the gnertor will block for as long as before -- no improvement except he has more flexibility when it will block.

Comment: Flexibility on when it will block is exactly what the OP was asking for, immediate return on button click and processing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was after something similar. I wanted yield to quickly return a value (if it could) while a background thread processed the next, next.

```
import Queue
import time
import threading

class MyGen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        # Put a first element into the queue, and initialize our thread
        self.i = 1
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, args=(self.queue, self.i))
        self.t.start()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def worker(self, queue, i):
        time.sleep(1) # Take a while to process
        queue.put(i**2)

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        while True: # Flush the queue
            try:
                self.queue.get(False)
            except Queue.Empty:
                break
        self.t.join()

    def next(self):
        # Start a thread to compute the next next.
        self.t.join()
        self.i += 1
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker, args=(self.queue, self.i))
        self.t.start()

        # Now deliver the already-queued element
        while True:
            try:
                print "request at", time.time()
                obj = self.queue.get(False)
                self.queue.task_done()
                return obj
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
            time.sleep(.001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = MyGen()
    for i in range(5):
#        time.sleep(2) # Comment out to get items as they are ready
        print "*********"
        print f.next()
        print "returned at", time.time()
```

The code above gave the following results:

```
*********
request at 1342462505.96
1
returned at 1342462505.96
*********
request at 1342462506.96
4
returned at 1342462506.96
*********
request at 1342462507.96
9
returned at 1342462507.96
*********
request at 1342462508.96
16
returned at 1342462508.96
*********
request at 1342462509.96
25
returned at 1342462509.96
```